# Pointer being freed was not allocated when implementing Matrix<T> class

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to build my own Matrix class and have overloaded the "*=" operator.
I am however running into problems with some pointer loss. I don't understand where my problem is at the moment.

Is it because I'm creating a new Matris "new_m" and this only lives inside the scope of the function? So I can't set the new pointer to data to the implied `(*this)` object?

Below is the code for my `*=` operator.

```
Matris<T> &operator*=(const Matris<T> &m){
     //if(m_cols != m.m_rows || m.rows != m.m_cols) throw new std::out_of_range("When multiplying two matrices they have to have be \"opposites\", that is one can be 1x2 and other one 2x1.");
     //else{
       unsigned int new_cap = m_rows * m.m_cols;
       Matris<T> new_m(sqrt(new_cap));
       new_m.m_vec = (T*) realloc(new_m.m_vec, new_cap*sizeof(T));
       std::memset (new_m.m_vec, 0, sizeof(T) * new_cap);
       for(size_t i = 0; i < m_rows; i++){
          for (size_t j = 0; j < m.m_cols; j++) {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < m_cols; k++) {
              new_m(i,j) += (*this)(i,k) * m(k,j);
            }
          }
       }
       m_vec = new_m.m_vec;
     //}
     return *this;
   }
```

And this is how I store and save my data in my Matris class:

```
private:
   size_t m_rows;
   size_t m_cols;
   size_t m_capacity;
   T * m_vec;
```

This is the constructor that is being called with an int:

```
explicit Matris(const unsigned int i){  //constructor with one integer, has to be integer, can't be negative or float.
     m_rows = i;
     m_cols = i;
     m_capacity = i*i;
     m_vec = (T*) malloc(i*i*sizeof(T));
     std::memset (m_vec, 0, sizeof (T) * i*i);
   }
```

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem. But it looks like you're setting `m_vec` to point to something that is then destroyed. You probably need to change `m_vec = new_m.m_vec;` to `*this = new_m;`.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` (or `realloc`) in C++. Those function only allocate memory, but they don't construct objects. So if `T` is anything but a primitive type (like e.g. `int` or `float`) then your program will not work. I also recommend you use e.g. `std::vector` instead, which have all the functionality you need built-in.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see. And how would I make that work? Should I copy the data from the new_m.m_vec to m_vec?

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 If the class is copyable, why not just copy the class? And if the class is not copyable, how can this possibly work?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't use std::vector I'm afraid since my teacher doesn't allow that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I feel so stupid! Ofc that's it :) Really appreciate it mate! I just copied it and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   m_vec = new_m.m_vec;
```

This makes `m_vec` point to part of the temporary object that's about to be destroyed. You want:

```
  *this = new_m;
```